# Выдвигающееся меню поверх layout PyQt5/PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pyside2, pyside

Можно ли реализовать выдвигающееся меню поверх layout(компоновки) в PyQt5/PySide2? Как пример меню калькулятора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Егор, наверное можно. Только вам надо показать что вы уже сделали и ваши попытки решения проблемы.